ASP.NET Core 8: authorization deny by claims
I am working with .NET 8 and need help configuring authorization policies. Specifically, I want the default policy to allow all users except those with the "external_employee" claim. Additionally, I need another policy to allow all users, including those with the external_employee claim.
The code base where I am working now includes thousands of endpoints, so my goal is to use the default policy to deny access to all endpoints for external employees. There are a few endpoints that should be accessible only if the ExternalEmployeeAllowed policy is applied.
The issue is that the ASP.NET Core authorization library evaluates both policies. When one policy fails, the result is always a 403 Forbidden error. I am looking for a solution to make this work correctly.
Thank you.
Authorization middleware configuration:
services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
        .AddPolicy("ExternalEmployeeAllowed", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser())
        .SetDefaultPolicy(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireAssertion(context =>
            {
                var guestClaim = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(e=>e.Type == "external_employee");
                var isGuest = guestClaim is not null;
                return !isGuest;
            })
            .Build());

Controller example:
[ApiController]
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "ExternalEmployeeAllowed")]
    [HttpGet("check1")]
    //Any authenticated user can access this endpoint and also the user has the claim external_employee
    public IActionResult GetCheck1() => Ok(); //This return 403 when a user has the claim external_employee

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("check2")]
    //Any authenticated user can access this endpoint but not if the user has the claim external_employee
    public IActionResult GetCheck2() => Ok(); //This works fine.
}


Hi @Diego Palat, it can work fine in my side, could you pls share your Program.cs and how do you add the claim? Also do you custom the IdentityUser model? Pls share enough code to reproduce your issue.

Be sure add the claim like below:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

   public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
   {
       _userManager = userManager;
   }

   public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
   {
       var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
       if (user != null)
       {
           var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
           if (!claims.Any(c => c.Type == "external_employee"))
           {
               // Add the claim to the user
               var claim = new Claim("external_employee", "true"); // Add this claim as needed
               await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim);
           }
       }
       return View();
   }
}

Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
        .AddPolicy("ExternalEmployeeAllowed", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser())
        .SetDefaultPolicy(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireAssertion(context =>
            {
                var guestClaim = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == "external_employee");
                var isGuest = guestClaim is not null;
                return !isGuest;
            })
            .Build());
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

